# Generate multiple insert queries via java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I have this query **"insert into pro_vendor (vendor_name,super_category,sub_category,created_by,vowes,wowes,created_date,`status`) values ('V','Sup','Sub','user','0','0',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'active')"**.

I implement one-liners by prepared statement usually or simply by statement.executeQuery(query), if I need to work on resultset.

Now the thing is that I have an array having multiple (maybe 1,maybe 2, maybe 50) different alternatives for the first argument viz vendor_name, so I want to generate insert queries using a loop.

I am unable to use prepared statement as I can't dynamically generate prepared statement objects, same for executeQuery as  I can't generate statement objects dynamically.

All I ask is a way to generate insert queries as per size of my array, thanks.

Comment: *use prepared statement*

Comment: seems easy but how can I dynamically create new prepared statement object as per size of my array ??

Comment: Either your explanation to very bad, or you are lost.  If you want to insert multiple pro_vendor records then create one `PreparedStatement` and loop setting the values e.g. `ps.SetString (1,  arr[0].getVendorName());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to insert multiple records you have to use batch insertion.

```
Connection conn;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("connection parameter's");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  // establish connection and make a table for the data.


            // COPY statement
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);


            // Drop table and recreate.
            stmt.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers CASCADE");
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE customers (CustID int, Last_Name  char(50), First_Name char(50),Email char(50), "
                            + "Phone_Number char(12))");

            // Some dummy data to insert. 
            String[] firstNames = new String[] { "Anna", "Bill", "Cindy","Don", "Eric" };
            String[] lastNames = new String[] { "Allen", "Brown", "Chu", "Dodd", "Estavez" };
            String[] emails = new String[] { "aang@example.com", "b.brown@example.com", "cindy@example.com","d.d@example.com", "e.estavez@example.com" };
            String[] phoneNumbers = new String[] { "123-456-7890", "555-444-3333", "555-867-5309", "555-555-1212", "781-555-0000" };
            // Create the prepared statement
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customers (CustID, Last_Name, " + 
                            "First_Name, Email, Phone_Number)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

            // Add rows to a batch in a loop. Each iteration adds a
            for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++) {

                pstmt.setInt(1, i + 1);
                pstmt.setString(2, lastNames[i]);
                pstmt.setString(3, firstNames[i]);
                pstmt.setString(4, emails[i]);
                pstmt.setString(5, phoneNumbers[i]);
                pstmt.addBatch();  // Add row to the batch.
            }

            try {
                // Batch is ready, execute it to insert the data
                pstmt.executeBatch();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
                return; // Exit if there was an error
            }

            // Commit the transaction to close the COPY command
            conn.commit();
            conn.close();
```

Comment: *you have to use batch insertion.* - don't have to, but a good idea

Comment: @ScaryWombat so can you suggest something without batch insertion ??just asking.

Comment: Yes, do the above but without adding to a batch, either auto-commit = true, or commit in your code.

Comment: @Dipak Aher Thanks bhai, this answer helped me !!